# GC statistics inside a docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core, garbage-collection, performance-testing

How can i find out GC statistics(rate , allocations and ....) of a .net core app inside a docker container(Linux) and number of threads which are used by that app?
I have tried docker API engine, performance counters and did not find any thing about GC.

Comment: You should be interested in various .NET CLI diagnostic tools, especially [`dotnet monitor`](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/exploring-your-net-applications-with-dotnetmonitor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Konrad Kokosa mentioned :

> .NET CLI diagnostic tools, especially dotnet monitor